# Adobe InDesign 2023 js - Modal dialog or alert is active

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to turn off ligatures and hyphenations in all style sheets. The script works, but I get an alert that I have to click through.

The specific line causing the issue seems to be

`!ev.isValid && app.eventListeners.add("afterOpen",myfunc).name = "onAfterOpen";`

Currently, I just click no to the dialog and don't show this again, but it would be nice to remove the problem if possible. Can anyone help?

```
main();
function main() {
var ev = app.eventListeners.itemByName ( "onAfterOpen" );
!ev.isValid && app.eventListeners.add("afterOpen",myfunc).name = "onAfterOpen";
}

function myfunc (myEvent){
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var allCharacterStyles = doc.allCharacterStyles;
var allParagraphStyles = doc.allParagraphStyles;

//alert ("Cleaning Character Styles.");
for (i = 1; i < allCharacterStyles.length; i++) {
allCharacterStyles[i].ligatures = false;
}

//alert ("Cleaning Paragraph Styles.");
for (i = 1; i < allParagraphStyles.length; i++) {
allParagraphStyles[i].ligatures = false;
allParagraphStyles[i].hyphenation = false;
}
//alert ("All Done.");

}
```

I've isolated the issue to one line:

`!ev.isValid && app.eventListeners.add("afterOpen",myfunc).name = "onAfterOpen";`

The error suggests a window is open, but I am not triggering a window.

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: I'd try to replace the line with `if (!ev.isValid) app.eventListeners.add("afterOpen",myfunc).name = "onAfterOpen";`

Comment: thank you, but that did not help. same alert.

Comment: Have you tried my fixed solution?

Comment: I have tried it and am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this variant of the code:

```
//@target "indesign"
//@targetengine "session"

main();

function main() {
    remove_listeners('afterOpen');
    app.eventListeners.add('afterOpen', myfunc);
}

function myfunc(event) {
    if (event.parent.constructor.name !== 'LayoutWindow') return; // <-- HERE
    var doc = app.activeDocument; // <-- HERE

    // or...
    // if (event.parent.constructor.name !== 'Document') return;
    // var doc = event.parent;

    var allCharacterStyles = doc.allCharacterStyles;
    var allParagraphStyles = doc.allParagraphStyles;

    // alert ("Cleaning Character Styles.");
    for (i = 1; i < allCharacterStyles.length; i++) {
        allCharacterStyles[i].ligatures = false;
    }

    // alert ("Cleaning Paragraph Styles.");
    for (i = 1; i < allParagraphStyles.length; i++) {
        allParagraphStyles[i].ligatures = false;
        allParagraphStyles[i].hyphenation = false;
    }
    // alert ("All Done.");
}

function remove_listeners(eventType) {
    var listeners = app.eventListeners;
    var i = listeners.length;
    while (i--) if (listeners[i].eventType == eventType) listeners[i].remove();
}
```

Alternatively you can replace the lines:

```
if (event.parent.constructor.name !== 'LayoutWindow') return;
var doc = app.activeDocument;
```

with:

```
if (event.parent.constructor.name !== 'Document') return;
var doc = event.parent;
```

or:

```
if (!(event.parent instanceof Document)) return;
var doc = event.parent;
```

It will run the function before the main window is show.

The handler 'afterOpen' runs twice. First its event is 'Document' (in this case there is no `app.activeDocument` yet, you have to use `var doc = event.parent` to address the opened document), the second event is 'LayoutWindow'.

Comment: this generated a new different error and also did not change the style sheet settings. https://imgur.com/zQiKR4h

Comment: Well. It works in CS6. But in CC2023 it doesn't work, indeed. I just changed the two lines in the code. Try it again.

Comment: I did not downvote this. FYi that wasnt me. Ive been teid up and jsut getting back to this now. Thank you very much for your help so far. I really appreciate it. The latest code is not working for me. I am trying to use this as a startup script, so that is part of the problem I think. But I also removed it from startup and tried your latest code as a triggered script from the script panel and get the same error.

Comment: Ok. Try to add the two lines at the top of the code `//@target "indesign"` and `//@targetengine "session"`

Comment: yuri, that last edit did it. Its working and it does not produce any error. I didn't need to use the optional change. I pasted it exactly as you put in above. This is amazing. I have been dealing with the stupid error message for awhile. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Btw, in my InDesign CC2023 (macOS) it still works if I use only `#targetengine "session"` instead of the two lines `//@target...`. Frankly, I don't even know the exactly meaning of these instructions, mostly they are redundant. And feel free to accept my answer as correct one.